# Linking two excel sheets on different computers without sharing files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, macros, links

I have two excel sheets, both are linked. one is input sheet and another one is output sheet. the data entered in input sheet updates on output sheet automatically as both are linked (both sheets are in same folder on same computer). What I want is input sheet should be in one computer and output sheet in another, then how can I connect these sheets so that when I enter data in input sheet in one computer, output sheet automatically gets updated on another computer without sharing any files.

Added from comment: i don't want the other person who is working with output sheet to see the input sheet and vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to put the workbooks into a place that both computers can access. In a company network that might be a folder on a file server. In a small home network you may need to share folders between computers.

You'll need **some** kind of sharing.

**Edit after comment:** if the output workbook has references to the input workbook, then at least the person who runs the output workbook will have access to the input workbook. If you don't want that, you may consider using a different approach, like a database with different user permissions, one for data entry and one for data reporting. Excel can be the input front-end for data that is stored in an Access or SQL database, and Excel can also use Access or SQL data as a source of reports.

Comment: thanku it might help me. . but the problem is i don't want the other person who is working with output sheet to see the input sheet and vice-versa.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Sheets. You'll need some way for the two sheets to communicate with each other.

Comment: Sharing is not the problem. The sheets communicate fine. Please read the question.

Comment: -1 Sharing is the issue between computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Dropbox or Skydrive to share this sheets between computers.

Comment: Sharing is not the problem. The sheets communicate fine. Please read the question.